# I need to calculate the revenue of the cars sold on a certain day

Tags: java, sum, jtable

I have a JTable and all the rows that it contains represent cars with the columns being certain details. Among those details are price and selling date.

The problem that I have encountered is that I have to calculate the sum of all the cars sold on a specific day. In other words is to calculate the sum of certain row-values from one column ("Price") with another column ("Selling date") as a constraint.

I input the date that I want to calculate on from a JDateChooser

```
if(rdbtnByDay.isSelected()){
    if(DayChooser.getDate() != null)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
        {

            if(carsTable.getValueAt(i, 10) != null)
            {

                int rowCount = carsTable.getRowCount();
                int sum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
                                        {
                    if(carsTable.getValueAt(j, 10) == CarProperties.sellingDate)
                    {
                        x = true;                                       
                    }

                    if (x == true)
                        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(carsTable.getValueAt(j, 8).toString());
                }
                                    Revenue.setText(Integer.toString(sum)); 
            }   
        }
    }

    else if (DayChooser.getDate() == null)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please add a valid day","UpdateError",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code:

```
if(carsTable.getValueAt(j, 10) == CarProperties.sellingDate)
{
    x = true;                                       
}

if (x == true)
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(carsTable.getValueAt(j, 8).toString());
```

... is that `x` never gets reset to `false`. Therefore once a car is deemed to be included, all subsequent cars are also included.

This could solve it:

```
if(carsTable.getValueAt(j, 10) == CarProperties.sellingDate)
{
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(carsTable.getValueAt(j, 8).toString());
}
```

**Edit**: You also need to not reset the `sum` to `0` within the loop. Move this line outside the for loop:

```
int sum = 0;  // this line needs to be outside the for loop
```

Comment: I changed it the way you suggested and now it outputs 0. I have also tried an "else" to change the x to false but the result is the same